# Lua string, insert one integer at every alternate index

Tags: lua

Say I have a string that contains "abcdef".

```
str1 = "abcdef"
```

I want to have another string str2 where it will have all the characters of str1 and at every alternate index have integer 1, like

```
str2:byte(1) = 1
str2:byte(2) = 'a'
str2:byte(3) = 1
str2:byte(4) = 'b'
str2:byte(5) = 1
str2:byte(6) = 'c'
```

So on ....

What is the fastest way I can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let Lua do the hard work with `gsub`:

```
str1 = "abcdef"
str2 = str1:gsub("(.)","%1\001")
print(str1:byte(1,-1))
print(str2:byte(1,-1))
```

This outputs

```
97  98  99  100 101 102
97  1   98  1   99  1   100 1   101 1   102 1
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice! But I think he wants `str2 = str1:gsub("(.)", "%1\001")` (i.e. a \001 added after every character in the original string.

Comment: Yes, with str2 = str1:gsub("(.)", "%1\001") , getting desired result

Comment: In case I want to have str2 as   1 , a, 1, b, 1, c .... , is it possible?

Comment: Got it. I just changed str2 = str1:gsub("(.)", "\001%1")

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't do assignment that way in Lua, i.e. `string.byte()` isn't used to *set* bytes.

You can iterate over the characters in `str1` and build `str2` character by character this way:

```
local str1 = "abc"
local str2 = ""
for i=1,#str1 do
    str2 = str2..string.sub(str1,i,i)..string.char(1)
end
```

Of course, if you print `str2` it will look like `str1` but their lengths will differ:

```
print(str1,str2)
print(#str1, #str2)
```

Give you this output:

```
abc     abc
3       6
```

On the other hand, if what you *really* want is to produce a string like "a1b1c1", then in that loop over the characters in `str1`, you need to do:

```
str2 = str2..string.sub(str1,i,i).."1"
```

And if you use `string.byte()` to examine `str2`

```
for i=1,#str2 do
     print( string.byte( str2, i ) )
end
```

you'll get this

```
97
1
98
1
99
1
```

where 97 is the ASCII byte for 'a', 98 is the byte for 'b', etc.

Comment: Thanks. What is string.char(0) , what value it will give.? I wanted str2 first element should be 1, second element should be from str1(1), third element 1 and fourth element from str1(2) so on ....

Comment: "The string.char and string.byte functions convert between characters and their internal numeric representations. The function string.char gets zero or more integers, converts each one to a character, and returns a string concatenating all those characters." (from "Programming in Lua" https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html )

Comment: Oh, that's true.  Sorry, I edited the answer to make it 1's.  See also the remark about "1" versus 1.